# Convert a picture or figure to EPS or PDF file

Tags: floats, pdf, diagrams, conversion, eps

In my document I'm embedding figures using the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
  \centering
  \def\svgwidth{1.2\columnwidth}
  \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
    \endlinechar=255\relax
    \begin{picture}(1,0.63636365)
      \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{figure.eps}}
      \put(0.50454546,0.58636365){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[b]{\smash{some text $ax^2+bx+c=0$.}}}
    \end{picture}
  }
  \caption{Caption.}
  \label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}
```

Where the image (`figure.eps`) contains no text and all annotations are added on top of the image using `\put` commands.

This method works very well (annotations can include any LaTeX macros, which is extremely useful) as long as I'm sticking to TeX. Now, however, I'd like to take the *resulting* figures (preferably in a vector format) and put them in some other tool.

Questions:

1. Is there any way of outputting these `float`s into PDF files with no margins, captions and with page dimensions equal to the specified `float` size? I imagine I'd have to somehow wrap each `float` in a `.tex` file with a custom preamble.
2. Is it possible to automate this process so that if I want to dump all my *N* figures to PDFs I don't have to repeat the step (1) *N* times.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`standalone`](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone).

Comment: @N.N.: for multi-page document I would use the [`preview`](http://ctan.org/pkg/preview) package directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general I recommend you to place all your complicated figures into separate files and use e.g. the `standalone` *class* to be able to compile them separatly and then `\input` them easily in the main document with the `standalone` *package*.

For your existing document you can use the `preview` package (which is used internally by `standalone`). It only compiles things wrapped in a `preview` environment and every such environment as a page. With the `tightpage` option you get tight pages as I requested.

I would use code like the following to redefine `figure` to use `preview` environments and to disable (or include) the `\caption`.
The resulting PDF should have one picture per page. You can then use the `page=<number>` option of `\includegraphics` to include it or split it into several PDFs using tools like `pdftk allfigures.pdf burst output figure%02d.pdf` or Ghostscript.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][]{%
    \begin{preview}%
        \renewcommand\caption[2][]{}% or
        %\def\@captype{figure}% If you want to include the caption
}{%
    \end{preview}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

text text text text 

\begin{figure}[!t]
    \rule{5cm}{8cm}% dummy replacement
    \caption{some caption}
\end{figure}

text text text text 

\begin{figure}[!t]
    \rule{8cm}{5cm}% dummy replacement
    \caption{some caption}
\end{figure}

text text text text 


\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. It works almost perfectly. "Almost" because there seems to be some problems with `resizebox` - it works fine up to width of ~12cm. Also, another, possibly related issue is that if I enable captions (as in your comment) all page widths are fixed to 4.79in (12.16cm).

Comment: @Andrzej: You need to comment out the new-line character which is taken as a space, i.e. write `\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%` instead of `\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{`. This is a common mistake. Or use the `adjustbox` package with `\begin{adjustbox}{width=\columnwidth} <content> \end{adjustbox}` instead.

Comment: @Andrzej: The `\caption` creates a new paragraph which is `\linewidth` wide. You could add a `{minipage}{<your linewidth>}` environment to change that, but I would not include the captions anyway.

Comment: thanks, it works. I had to comment out all whitespaces (not just after `resizebox`) but that is not a problem. Thanks again, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with your procedures so far, I suppose you could set `\pagestyle{empty}` in the preamble, have only one float per page by inserting a `\clearpage` instruction after each float, and finally break up the resulting *n*-page pdf file into *n* separate pdf files. (Setting the pagestyle to empty will simplify cropping each page.)